# Loop out ACF data from flexible content

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Flexible content group with 2 columns. 1 for title and one for anchor id.
See pic 1.
[pic of flexible content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Tqe.png)

I’m trying to loop out the anchor links(id) and the title like this:

```
<?php if( have_rows('links') ): ?>
      <?php 
       $links = get_sub_field('links');
      foreach ($links as $link) :
        $anchor = ($link['id']) ? 'href="#' . $link['id'] . '"' : "";
      ?>
        <li class="side-menu__item"> 
          
        <a class="menu__link" <?= $anchor ?>>
            <?= $link['title']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

However nothing shows up so I'm guessing i'm looping it out the wrong way, or not looping it at all. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing your `while` loop.

Comment: `while ( have_rows('links') ) : the_row(); /**All your stuff here **/ endwhile;`